# Filling between quantile ranges

Tags: plotting, manipulate, filling

Following code plots Quantiles for a GBM process.

```
ranges = {.01, .05, .25, .5, .75, .95, .99};
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Quantile[
    GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[μ, σ, 100000][t],ranges],
 {t, 1, 30},PlotRange -> {0, 1500000}], 
{μ, .07, .1}, {σ, .07, .20}]
```

I would like to shade the area between the ranges

.01 to .05 and .95 to .99 say lt. blue
.05 to .25 and .75 to .95 say med. blue
.25 to .75 say dark blue with the .5 quantile line thick black

Plot options seems to allow filling between curves using

```
Filling->{{1}->2}
```

syntax but not sure how or if that can be applied here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that your list spec in the `Filling` suggestion is the other way around. You mean

```
Filling->{1->{2}}
```

With this style you can incorporate the filling style directly there and therefore, what you want can be written down as

```
ranges = {.01, .05, .25, .5, .75, .95, .99};
col =col = RGBColor[.6, .6, 1];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Quantile[
    GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[μ, σ, 100000][t], 
    ranges], {t, 1, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, 1500000}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, col}, 2 -> {{3}, Darker[col]}, 
              3 -> {{5}, Darker@Darker[col]}, 5 -> {{6}, Darker[col]},
              6 -> {{7}, col}}], 
{μ, .07, .1}, {σ, .07, .20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For more functions to plot, you should maybe create this specification automatically.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, had list spec reversed which didn't help ;-)